# flutter : Infinite scrolling is not working

Tags: flutter, scroll, scrollview, infinite

I used a package Pagination_view, but it crashed when the data amount was huge. that's why I make a reusable widget for infinite scroll. Here my widget code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfiniteScrollList<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<List<T>> Function(int offset, int limit) fetchData;
  final int initialOffset;
  final int limit;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T item) itemBuilder;
  final Key Function(T item)? itemKey;
  final Widget? initialLoadingIndicator;
  final Widget? emptyState;
  final Widget? errorState;
  final Widget? customRefreshIndicator;
  final void Function()? onRetry;
  final bool enablePullToRefresh;
  final bool enableInfiniteScroll;
  final Widget Function()? separatorBuilder;
  final ScrollController? scrollController;

  const InfiniteScrollList({
    Key? key,
    required this.fetchData,
    this.initialOffset = 0,
    this.limit = 5,
    required this.itemBuilder,
    this.itemKey,
    this.initialLoadingIndicator,
    this.emptyState,
    this.errorState,
    this.customRefreshIndicator,
    this.onRetry,
    this.enablePullToRefresh = true,
    this.enableInfiniteScroll = true,
    this.separatorBuilder,
    this.scrollController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  InfiniteScrollListState<T> createState() => InfiniteScrollListState<T>();
}

class InfiniteScrollListState<T> extends State<InfiniteScrollList<T>> {
  List<T> items = [];
  int offset = 0;
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isRefreshing = false;
  bool isError = false;
  ScrollController? _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    offset = widget.initialOffset;
    _scrollController = widget.scrollController ?? ScrollController();
    fetchData();
    _scrollController!.addListener(() => onEndScroll(_scrollController!));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    if (isLoading || isError) return;

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final newData = await widget.fetchData(offset, widget.limit);

      setState(() {
        items.addAll(newData);
        offset += widget.limit;
        isLoading = false;
        isError = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        isError = true;
      });
      print('Error fetching data: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> onRefresh() async {
    if (isRefreshing || isError || !widget.enablePullToRefresh) return;

    setState(() {
      isRefreshing = true;
    });

    try {
      final refreshedData = await widget.fetchData(0, widget.limit);

      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(refreshedData);
        offset = widget.limit;
        isRefreshing = false;
        isError = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isRefreshing = false;
        isError = true;
      });
      print('Error refreshing data: $e');
    }
  }

  void onEndScroll(ScrollController controller) {
    if (!isLoading &&
        !isRefreshing &&
        widget.enableInfiniteScroll &&
        controller.position.pixels >= controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: onRefresh,
      child: isError
          ? (widget.onRetry != null
              ? _buildErrorWidgetWithRetry()
              : (widget.errorState ?? _buildErrorWidget()))
          : (items.isEmpty && isLoading
              ? (widget.initialLoadingIndicator ??
                  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()))
              : (items.isEmpty
                  ? (widget.emptyState ?? Center(child: Text('No items found.')))
                  : _buildInfiniteList())),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInfiniteList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: items.length + (widget.enableInfiniteScroll ? 1 : 0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index < items.length) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              if (widget.separatorBuilder != null && index > 0)
                widget.separatorBuilder!(),
              widget.itemBuilder(context, items[index]),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return widget.customRefreshIndicator ??
              Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
      controller: _scrollController,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildErrorWidget() {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Error loading data.'),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildErrorWidgetWithRetry() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('Error loading data. Tap to retry.'),
        SizedBox(height: 16),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: widget.onRetry,
          child: Text('Retry'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to use this widget under another list view, where many other widgets are present. But this custom widget data is not load automatically when the user scroll down at the end, even `onEndScroll` is not called.  where is the problem? How can I solve this ?

Comment: Maybe one of the condition inside `onEndScroll` is false every time. Try printing something above that condition and check if it gets called.

Comment: @Pokaboom nope, I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to the InfiniteScrollList widget's constraint is 0.0<=h<=Infinity, so the scroll can't receive scroll event. so you can give InfiniteScrollList widget a height constraint. like wrap InfiniteScrollList  with SizedBox widget.

Comment: I want to scroll like Facebook, where List and other widget scroll together but only list is infinite scroll. If I use sizedbox, then other widgets are not scroll with list.